# Share an Internet connection with multiple devices

Tags: proxy, router, connection-sharing

I'm in China and I'm using GoAgent to get rid of the great firewall. I would like to create a custom network for my office. My primary computer is connected through LAN to a wireless router (with which I still have to use a proxy (GoAgent) in order to connect to the Internet). I would like to share the Internet connection my computer gets with the same wireless router I am connected to, so every mobile device and laptop on the network will be able to use the same connection as my primary PC.

Is it possible to use the same router for sharing the connection or do I need to use another one?

Comment: How about to organize next: share/provide your internet to the another router (the second one, if you can find it), and then connect all your user to that one?

Comment: Where is GoAgent proxy installed? On your router, or on your pc? Also: which OS do you use?

Comment: By reading around, I cannot understand whether GoAgent modifies your whole routing table, or just it provides proxies for your Web browser.

Comment: Can you post your routing table with and without GoAgent activated? TY

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar to the whole *GoAgent* thing, but maybe you can try this:

I understand your computer has two network cards:

1. One Wireless card for connecting to your router (this is okay, no need to modify this).
2. Other network card (I assume it's ethernet).

---

1. Setup another subnet address and range on secondary (eth) network card.
2. Create bridged connection between these two network cards.
3. Connect your your secondary wireless router with LAN cable to the secondary (eth) network card.
4. Setup router correctly (WAN port will use your computer's subnet range, LAN ports will use different subnet range. Gateway is your primary router. Primary DNS server will be primary router as well, secondary DNS should be your provider's (this is a little bit tricky, because I don't live in China; so I'm not sure).
5. Set up correct routing & NAT.
6. Set up DHCP server on your secondary router if needed (or if you dont plan assign addresses manualy).

I'm not sure how will Windows behave when bridging two network cards with different addresses, but I assume it should work.
Maybe this solutions won't 100% fit, but you can reply here with result and I believe we will make it work.